# How to compare two sets, where each element of them is list?

Tags: python, list, set

Here's my code.

```
a = [
        ['StarList', 'StarId38', 'ShipList']
    ]
b = [
        ['StarList', 'StarId3', 'ShipList'],
        ['StarList', 'StarId4', 'ShipList']
    ]
assert set(a) == set(b) # False

a = [
        ['StarList', 'StarId4', 'ShipList'],
        ['StarList', 'StarId3', 'ShipList']
    ]
assert set(a) == set(b) # True
```

It doesn't work:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "compare.py", line 8, in <module>
        assert set(a) == set(b) # False
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Well, how to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Convert the inner lists to tuple or some other hashable type before comparing.

```
In [52]: a = [                               
        ['StarList', 'StarId38', 'ShipList']
    ]

In [53]: b = [                               
        ['StarList', 'StarId3', 'ShipList'],
        ['StarList', 'StarId4', 'ShipList']
    ]

In [54]: set(map(tuple, a)) == set(map(tuple, b))
Out[54]: False

In [55]: a = [
   ....:         ['StarList', 'StarId4', 'ShipList'],
   ....:         ['StarList', 'StarId3', 'ShipList']
   ....:     ]

In [56]: set(map(tuple,a))==set(map(tuple,b))
Out[56]: True
```

Comment: This creates intermediate lists, sets, and tuples, which may be perfectly fine.  If it is acceptable to change the order of the sublists, sort each and then compare.

Answer (score 2):

`set()` does not work when the elements of a list are unhashable (e.g. are a list). So first you should considerer if you really must use `set`. An alternative to remove duplicates in this case is `itertools.groupby`:

```
import itertools
unique_a = [k for k,_ in itertools.groupby(a)]
unique_b = [k for k,_ in itertools.groupby(b)]
unique_a.sort()
unique_b.sort()
```

And try (for your second case):

```
>>> unique_a == unique_b
True
```

Comment: -1.  `aList.sort()` returns `None`, therefore `unique_a.sort() == unique_b.sort()` will always be `True` because `None == None`.  Try for example `[1].sort() == [3, 2].sort()`.

Comment: Steven Rumbalski: you're right, thanks for pointing out the error. I edited the answer to put the sort earlier.